# Renaming executable changes behavior

Tags: unix

I don't know if this question, is really fit for this fora, it likely isn't, but nevertheless here we go;

After just running an invalid command on a unix program; I got the familiar;

```
Usage: PROGRAM [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

As I was in the progress of reviewing a program, while I did this a thought sprang to mind. Namely that a C++ program, could easily be implemented, to change behavior based upon the name of the executable (i.e. by the first argument in `argv`).

I have absolutely no idea why this would be useful, I know that the `argv[0]` can be useful, but has anyone ever seen a program, which did this (change behavior on name change) and achieved something by doing so?

Comment: You can also change it.  Then ps shows the new name!  Fun, but not that useful.

Comment: Is this allowed by the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is routine (but well done for realizing that it can be done).  For example:

```
$ (cd /usr/bin; ls -li | grep -w vim)
 2704450 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel         3 Oct 31  2013 ex -> vim
 2704451 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel         3 Oct 31  2013 rview -> vim
 2704452 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel         3 Oct 31  2013 rvim -> vim
 2378579 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel         3 Oct 31  2013 vi -> vim
 2704453 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel         3 Oct 31  2013 view -> vim
 2343880 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel   1472736 Oct 31  2013 vim
 2704454 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel         3 Oct 31  2013 vimdiff -> vim
$
```

So, the `vim` executable can also be invoked as `vimdiff` or `view` or `vi` or `ex` and it will behave differently depending on how it is invoked.  On some systems, these will be hard links instead of symlinks (the data is from Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks), so you'd need to `grep` for the inode number instead of `vim`.

Another example:

Bash operates differently when invoked as `bash` compared with when it is invoked as `sh`. Classically, shells recognize when they're invoked with a dash `-` in front of their name (`-sh`, `-bash`, etc), and act as login shells when you do that:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
39301 ttys000    0:01.30 -bash
46766 ttys001    0:00.24 -bash
$
```

Comment: Wow, that's nice; I didn't knew it had real life application. Is applications like busybox implemented like this as well? - I had the idea, that these things were implemented via. hidden commands passed to the executable, but apparently not.

Comment: I'm vaguely aware of Busybox; I'd guess that it works along these lines, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I have a program, `sqlcmd` (pre-dating Microsoft's johnny-come-lately by a decade or more!) which has links `sqlunload` and `sqlreload` and it behaves differently depending on which name is used (though you can also drive it into 'unload' mode with `-U` option and 'reload' mode with `-R`).

Comment: Even before `vim`, vi was the visual mode of the line editor ex, and was a hardlink to the same executable.

Comment: @rojomoke: agreed, but it is harder to provide evidence of that old behaviour on modern systems.  The technique has a long history. If you can find Unix SVR4 manuals, you'll find that `ed` could also be invoked as `red` (restricted editor); `sh` could also be invoked as `rsh` (restricted — not remote — shell) or `jsh` (job shell); and `ksh` could also be invoked as `rksh` (restricted Korn shell).